# How to debug failing gdalinfo /viscurl?

Tags: gdal, gdalinfo

A gdalinfo is failing as it is stopping forever after naming the Driver:

```
$ gdalinfo  "/vsicurl/https://example.com/download/my_file.tiff"      
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
```

When I download the file with curl and look at the header I cannot spot something odd:

```
$ gdalinfo my_file.tiff

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: my_file.tiff
Size is 3623, 5130
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
GeoTransform =
  44.50717077241472, 1.198476664818068e-06, -6.74965412170429e-14
  41.52660288972159, -2.481700477227925e-13, -9.005126117852543e-07
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=RealityCapture
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  LAYOUT=COG
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  44.5071708,  41.5266029) ( 44d30'25.81"E, 41d31'35.77"N)
Lower Left  (  44.5071708,  41.5219833) ( 44d30'25.81"E, 41d31'19.14"N)
Upper Right (  44.5115129,  41.5266029) ( 44d30'41.45"E, 41d31'35.77"N)
Lower Right (  44.5115129,  41.5219833) ( 44d30'41.45"E, 41d31'19.14"N)
Center      (  44.5093418,  41.5242931) ( 44d30'33.63"E, 41d31'27.46"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 1811x2565, 905x1282, 452x641, 226x320
Band 2 Block=512x512 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 1811x2565, 905x1282, 452x641, 226x320
Band 3 Block=512x512 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 1811x2565, 905x1282, 452x641, 226x320
Band 4 Block=512x512 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Overviews: 1811x2565, 905x1282, 452x641, 226x320
```

What could cause vsicurl to stop, or how can I debug `gdalinfo with vsicurl` ?

Comment: Add `--debug on --config CPL_CURL_VERBOSE YES`.

Comment: Thanks this helped me to find ther error. I disabled the loading of an aux.xml file with GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN=EMPTY_DIR and all is working